# How to show $ \sup\limits_{k}||u_k||_{W^{1.q}(U)}<\infty $?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

If $u_k\rightharpoonup u$  weakly in $W^{1,q}(U)$, how can I show 
$$
\sup\limits_{k}||u_k||_{W^{1.q}(U)}<\infty?
$$

Comment: This is a general fact from functional analysis: If $X$ is a Banach space and $x_n\to x$ weakly, then $\sup_n \| x_n\|_X<\infty$, and this follows from the uniform boundedness principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second @Jose27's answer. This is the general fact from functional analysis. For a proof, please see Proposition 3.5 in this [book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387709130).

Moreover, the converse is also true as well. If a sequence of function is uniformly bounded in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $\Omega$ bounded and satisfies some boundary regularity, then, up to a subsequence, you can extract a weak convergence sequence.